# Charge from a card to specific merchant - Stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments

Let me illustrate my payment logic first off all.

> I have two user-level in my app

- **Service provider** will set up his bank a/c's to receive payment. So, I have created a customer **Merchant1** in stripe then added & verified an a/c under that customer object. then saved the customer id for using it later.
- **Customer** will add his cards for making payment for a service. I have created a customer **Customer1** and added card under then saved the customer id .

Now I have to charge from **Customer1** to **Merchant1**. Everything is works well except the final procedure IE, Charging.

I have gone through stripe [charging](https://stripe.com/docs/charges) docs but I couldn't find out how to charge directly from **Customer1** to **Merchant1**.

By using the following code I had tried out but It seems the destination account should be connected to use the param `destination`. *Ain't understand what's a connected account*. I just want to tranfer from one customer card to other ones account. I'm stucked completely. **Pl. offer me a helping hand**.

```
// Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
// See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_BQokikJOvBiI2HlWgH4olfQ2");

\Stripe\Charge::create(array(
  "amount" => 1500,
  "currency" => "usd",
  "customer" => $customer_id, // Previously stored, then retrieved
  "destination" => {CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}
));
```

And also tried with the below snippet but that giving an error response like `Merchant not found`

```
 $charge_deails = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
       "amount" => "300",
       "currency" => "usd",
       "customer" => "***", 
       "destination"=>"**",
       "description" => $requestParams['additional_description']));
```

**Any help would greatly appreciated.**

### **Update**

Attachment for clarification

> Two customers `An` and `Raju` were `An` is the customer and added a
>   card to make payment and `Raju` is the service provide who need to
>   receive payment.

[image]

> Card added under `An`

[image]

> Account added under `Raju`

[image]

*Like this there would be many customers and providers those need to dynamically accept and make payment automatically using stripe API's.*

Answer (score 1):

[Customers](https://stripe.com/docs/api#customer_object) are payment *sources*. They can provide funds, but not receive them.

In order to accept payments on behalf of third parties, you must use [Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/docs/connect). You would create [accounts](https://stripe.com/docs/api#account_object) (not customers) for your merchants.

I recommend you spend some time browsing through Connect's documentation, and reach out directly to [Stripe's support](https://support.stripe.com/email) if you have questions about how to apply Connect to your specific business model.

Comment: I'm not using third party a/c's but adding a/c's under customers using stripe samples https://stripe.com/docs/testing#managed-accounts. So basically out there 2 users with many-many relation ship
service providers and cutomers. when a customer buying a product the service provider would receive the payment. service providers can create and verify a/c's via android app. and customers also can add card via app to make payment when click buy.

Comment: So when a customer buy a product the service provider should get paid automatically.

Comment: Could u pl. look at the attachments to getting it right my requirements

Comment: So does u mean I should go for managed account model to implement the architecture ? https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#create_account

Comment: Could u pl. elaborate the steps to accomplish it.